# Paypal Virtual terminal from intranet application

Tags: paypal

I have a site that I've set up for a church to sell stuff through.  The site is user/password protected, so not anyone can just hop on and use it.

The thing is, it's more like a intranet application, than an exposed internet site.  Currently, we have a card scanner and when someone wants to purchase something, we use the card scanner to complete the purchase.

The real big requirement is that people can order over the phone or in person, but not directly through the website (they have to come pick the stuff up).

They want paypal integrated into the site itself, but from what I've seen on the APIs, there's no way to build in a virtual terminal to a site like this.

Is that correct?  Is there a way to do what the paypal virtual terminal does, but from a normal website?

Meaning, the salesman takes the card information, plugs it in.  hits sumbit, and viola, the sale goes through.  Instead of the end user plugging their info it and hitting submit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you're correct, there is no way to use PayPal's virtual terminal in the manner you suggest. However, you can create multiple users on the account with varying levels of access. You could give a user permissions to run VT transactions while restricting access to other areas of the account. See [Multi-User Access](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/logins-outside) for more information.